# One-line syntax to read and return file on Python using with

Tags: python, contextmanager

I need to read a file and return result: this is the syntax I use

```
return json.loads(with open(file, 'r') as f: f.read())
```

I know that we cannot write `with open` in one line, so I look for the correct syntax to fix that.

Comment: Note `with` is a *context manager*, not a loop: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-with-statement. It's also not really about having it on one line, so much trying to use a statement as an argument to a function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The requirement to do this in a single line is dubious, but you can easily fix the syntax:

```py
with open(file, 'r') as f: return json.loads(f.read())
```

Having `json` read the file for you is probably both more idiomatic and more elegant:

```py
with open(file, 'r') as f: return json.load(f)
```

Python allows you to write a "suite" of statements after the colon to create a block in a single line. Anything which looks like

```py
whatever in a block: do things; more stuff
```

is equivalent to the multi-line

```py
whatever in a block:
  do things
  more stuff
```